# Django allauth override clean_username and clean_email function

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Hi have created a custom user model and introduced new fields for registration  say for ex: phone and created custom adapter to save the field to database, but at the time of validation. clean_username() is used to check username already exist or not  i need to check phone no for that username. so checking both username and phone no at same time. how can i get the phone no inside clean_username function. the below is the clean_username function in django allauth adapter

```
def clean_username(self, username, shallow=False):
    """
    Validates the username. You can hook into this if you want to
    (dynamically) restrict what usernames can be chosen.
    """             

    if not USERNAME_REGEX.match(username):
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Usernames can only contain "
                                      "letters, digits and @/./+/-/_."))

    # TODO: Add regexp support to USERNAME_BLACKLIST
    username_blacklist_lower = [ub.lower()
                                for ub in app_settings.USERNAME_BLACKLIST]
    if username.lower() in username_blacklist_lower:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Username can not be used. "
                                      "Please use other username."))
    # Skipping database lookups when shallow is True, needed for unique
    # username generation.
    if not shallow:
        username_field = app_settings.USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD
        #appuuid_field = app_settings.USER_MODEL_APPID_FIELD
        assert username_field
        user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            query = {username_field + '__iexact': username}                
            user_model.objects.get(**query)     
        except user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _("This username is already taken. Please choose another."))
    return username
```

Comment: how can i get the phone details from the form in clean_username function to validate it along with username

Answer (score 2):

You can validate only that specific field in the clean_{fieldname} function. For your case, you have to override the clean function, as your validation mechanism spans across different fields.

Your clean function will look something like this:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm as AllAuthSignupForm

class SignupForm(AllAuthSignupForm):
    def clean(self):
        super(SignupForm, self).clean()
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
        if not self._custom_username_phone_check(username, phone) and not self.errors:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Your username and phone do not match."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```